# firebase init bash: firebase: command not found

Tags: firebase, npm

NO me reconoce el paquete npm, estoy trabado con un tema no puedo instalar firebase i -g firebase-tools
osea lo instalo pero cuando le doy firebase init no me reconoce el paquete alguien sabe como solucionarlo estoy en windows.

npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase init

**firebase init bash: firebase: command not found**

Answer (score 1):

para instalar usa

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

y luego usa

```
firebase login
```

Comment: Si amigo pero estoy en windows. no me reconoce ese comando

Comment: Pude solucionarlo, tengo que autenticarse con google antes desde Hosting de Firebase antes por eso nunca me iba tomar esos comando, antes previamente tenes que aver puesto el script que te da firebase en un proyecto. luego va **npm install -g firebase-tools** luego cuando queres hostearlo te la opción de loguarte o autenticarse.  MI error era querer loguearme en un proyecto sin nada por nunca me hiba a andar en windows por eso al poner **firebase init** me salia el error.

Comment: IMPORTANTE yo lo hice con webpack, en la consola tenes que poner  **ls** para quedar al mismo nivel de la carpeta src y dist o public luego de haberte logueado recien poner firebase init,